# jquery loop through json

Tags: jquery, json

Hi I am trying to loop through a json file like so:

```
$.each(data.playlists.playlist, function(i, item) {

              $("#contentC").append('<p>' + item.id + '</p>'); 
              $("#contentC").append('<p>' + item.title + '</p>'); 
              $("#contentC").append('<p>' + item.url + '</p>'); }
           );
```

**json:**

```
{
   "playlists":{
      "playlist":[
         {
            "id":"8391802",
            "title":"Second Playlist",
            "description":"",
            "date":"2011-03-06T18:53:33",
            "size":"10",
            "duration":"2267",
            "streamable":"0",
            "creator":"http:\/\/www.last.fm\/user\/jon21021985",
            "url":"http:\/\/www.last.fm\/user\/jon21021985\/library\/playlists\/4zv5m_second_playlist",
            "image":[
               {
                  "#text":"",
                  "size":"small"
               },
               {
                  "#text":"",
                  "size":"medium"
               },
               {
                  "#text":"",
                  "size":"large"
               },
               {
                  "#text":"",
                  "size":"extralarge"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":"8372409",
            "title":"All-american Rejects",
            "description":"",
            "date":"2011-02-28T13:30:01",
            "size":"6",
            "duration":"785",
            "streamable":"0",
            "creator":"http:\/\/www.last.fm\/user\/jon21021985",
            "url":"http:\/\/www.last.fm\/user\/jon21021985\/library\/playlists\/4zg6x_all-american_rejects",
            "image":[
               {
                  "#text":"",
                  "size":"small"
               },
               {
                  "#text":"",
                  "size":"medium"
               },
               {
                  "#text":"",
                  "size":"large"
               },
               {
                  "#text":"",
                  "size":"extralarge"
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "@attr":{
         "user":"jon21021985"
      }
   }
}
```

the problem is the data changes if there is only one playlist then I get 'undefined'

```
   {
   "playlists":{
      "playlist":{
         "id":"1319510",
         "title":"Untitled",
         "description":"",
         "date":"2007-10-18T12:17:58",
         "size":"1",
         "duration":"345",
         "streamable":"0",
         "creator":"http:\/\/www.last.fm\/user\/john",
         "url":"http:\/\/www.last.fm\/user\/john\/library\/playlists\/sa52_",
         "image":[
            {
               "#text":"",
               "size":"small"
            },
            {
               "#text":"",
               "size":"medium"
            },
            {
               "#text":"",
               "size":"large"
            },
            {
               "#text":"",
               "size":"extralarge"
            }
         ]
      },
      "@attr":{
         "user":"john"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if($.isArray(data.playlists.playlist))
{
             $.each(data.playlists.playlist, function(i, item) {
               displayPlayList(item)
           ); 
}
else
{
      displayPlayList(data.playlists.playlist);
}


    //this way of appending an element is very poor coding practice but 
    //i have done  this way, because u yourself have written this
    // if u want then i can suggest you, how can u optimize this code
    function displayPlayList(item)
    {
                  $("#contentC").append('<p>' + item.id + '</p>'); 
                  $("#contentC").append('<p>' + item.title + '</p>'); 
                  $("#contentC").append('<p>' + item.url + '</p>'); }

    }
```

**Edit**

As Emmet has pointed out you should always return array. But its acceptable in scenarios where you  are using that party json services and they are returning data in that format, then there is nothing you can do

Comment: excellent this works fine, thanks for the help. If you can optimise the code that would be great, I only wrote it this way as I am bvery much a beginner with jquery. thanks again...J