# Looping over strings in JSON

Tags: jquery

My JSON looks like this:

```
{"RoomNoList":[{"RoomNo":"ML100"},{"RoomNo":"ML100"},{"RoomNo":"ML100"},{"RoomNo":"ML100"}]}
```

I want to loop over the strings and get `RoomNo` values.

Comment: It would have taken you a quarter of the time just to google this.  If you aren't willing to put in a minimal amount of effort, how can you expect people to write code for you?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212773/jquery-loop-through-json |  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980113/jquery-loop-through-json  |  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041497/loop-through-json-result-with-jquery  |  Those were just a few of the first links.  Took me around 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job in modern browsers:

```
var numbers = obj.roomNoList.map(function(item) {
    return item.RoomNo;
};
```

With jQuery:

```
var numbers = $.map(obj.roomNoList, function(item) {
    return item.RoomNo;
});
```

See also: [`jQuery.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way.

```
for(i=0; objJson.RoomNoList.length; i++)
    alert(objJson.RoomNoList[i].RoomNo)
```